# Why Nuxt static generate add source json and js files to build?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, static-site-generation

In a Nuxt project, I am generating static pages by fetching data from a local JSON file. When I run `yarn generate`, everything works perfectly. However, alongside the static HTML files in the /public/_nuxt directory, there is also the source JSON file and all my functions for processing it. These are being loaded on every page for some reason. Why?

As an example, I have created a very simple project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-efxtet?file=pages%2Findex.vue

On the homepage (/pages/index.vue), links to pages are generated, and on each page, `[itemName]/index.vue` displays text from `data/pageData.json`. When I run `yarn generate`, its make all `[itemName]/index.html` with rendered text. But also a file called `pageData.8c96f53e.js` is created in the _nuxt directory with source data for generating htmls. But the pages are already generated, so why make redundant requests and copy the source data? How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

The static pages and generate, is normaly for serverless web apps. It means all pages will be generated and ready to send it to client without any more proccess. Therefor on "npm run generate" all pages produce and for all your dynamic pages, you have a file, even for [itemName]/index.vue. I hope you get the right answer.

Comment: Perhaps I worded my question poorly. I just want to get static pages for all routes. And they are created. But each page includes `<link rel="modulepreload" as="script" crossorigin href="/_nuxt/_pageData_.3b6d9cda.js">` with the original json data for the page that is already used in it! If you remove this “script”, the page will be displayed completely correctly. Why load extra data?

Comment: because if the client close the explorer and open and enterd to another page of your web app the js and all should be prepare. other wise it does not enter to the other page. every page should be copeleted. Ok?

Comment: because if any come directly to different web page should have access to that script. otherwise the app does not work, ....